# More Word Riddles

Tags: riddle, word

I am an unit of measure,
and a barrier that protects the watchers and bounces the ball.
Many wear me day but not night,
while as a verb, I am either constructive, violent or incredibly destructive.
Still, I come from much shattered stone,
but sometimes also warn of storms.
I am quite sure you will see right through me.

What am I?

Comment: You need to pace yourself. Put some time between posting riddles. :P

Comment: Also, it's spelled "measure".

Comment: @mbomb007. Correct. I'll fix that. (Frenchman here, so some of those pass me by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Glass ?

I am an unit of measure,

> A glass, or a cup

and a barrier that protects the watchers and bounces the ball.

> A glass screen

Many wear me day but not night,

> Glasses

while as a verb, I am either constructive, violent or incredibly destructive.

> To glass = strike with a glass or a bottle

Still, I come from much shattered stone,
but sometimes also warn of storms.

> Glass is made from sand

I am quite sure you will see right through me.

> Glass is transparent

Comment: You got it. Care to add what's missing?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glass#Verb)?

Comment: Yup. #1, 3 & 4 on that page.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Light

**Reasoning:**

I am an unit of measure,

> If something doesn't weigh much, it is "light"

and a barrier that protects the watchers and bounces the ball.

> Light is between you what you are watching with your eyes

Many wear me day but not night,

> Light is absent during the night, but on us during day

while as a verb, I am either constructive, violent or incredibly destructive.

> Light a fire

Still, I come from much shattered stone,

> Flint can create sparks

but sometimes also warn of storms.

> Lightning

I am quite sure you will see right through me.

> Because light is immaterial

Comment: I think unit of measure probably refers more to the sciency stuff (Physics). I thought *your answer* too, but couldn't get the 4th line to fit. Nice one :)

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that same thing. Regarding the first line, I would have gone with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-year).